# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() with CLASSIFICATION ALGORITHMS

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from joblib import dump, load
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

X = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rafae\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\SOAM\\KSPasswordData.csv")
y = X.pop('subject').values
X_train = scaler.fit(X, y)

y_test = scaler.transform(X, y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

scaler.transform(X_train)

clf.fit(X_train)
score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

print(score)

dump(clf, 'exemplo.jlb')
```

This is the error:

```sh
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: no, don't answer my question

Comment: In any case you're example is not reproducible. Please add a data sample.